# Github equivalent to Launchpad "Questions & Answers"

Tags: github, launchpad

For Launchpad projects, it is possible to offer community support thanks to the [Questions & Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/). How can I enable similar functionality for my Github project? Is there something already offered by Github, or some other site? The purpose is to help with for example software installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Q&A functionality in Github. Q&As and forums can, however, be created at other sites, for example googlegroups.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's nothing like that on GitHub. However, exploiting available tools, I would use the project wiki to build a knowledge base about your software, and the issue tracker (perhaps with some kind of "documentation" category/label) as a mean to reproduce Q&A threads, which ideally should result in a wiki page (that you'll need to put together yourself) with some kind of definitive answer to the specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although I'm not convinced that using the issue tracker and the wiki is easier and more maintainable than simply using a standard forum.

Comment: GitHub's tracker allows for comments by those who participate to the issue, so that may be comparable to a discussion thread in a forum, I think. However, I feel forums to be a little bit too scattered for my taste, so I would complement it with a wiki in order to save users the pain of running through a full discussion. Note you could also use wiki pages for discussion and collective building of answers, avoiding the issue tracker altogether; but you'd need to rearrange content every now and then anyway.

Comment: OK. But I still feel that wikis are unsuitable to use for Q&A.